# How to split and loop over strings inside a match in rust

Tags: rust

I'm just starting to learn Rust and built a sample api project using Rocket and rusqlite. I want to get all of the items in my database through a get endpoint. My table has an id field and a string which is a list of ids seperated by ,. After getting this back I want to split this string and go back to the database for each entry and then create a struct for it. I'm having trouble figuring this out in a functional way for rust. Does anyone have any advice for how to proceed? I want to manipulate the data myself and avoid orm tools like diseil.

data.rs

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Item {
    pub id: i32,
    pub time_tp_prepare: i32,
    pub name: String
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Table {
    pub id: i32,
    pub items: Vec<Item>
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct StatusMessage {
    pub message: String
}
```

database.rs

```
use rusqlite::Result;

pub struct ItemData {
    pub id: i32,
    pub time_tp_prepare: i32,
    pub name: String
}

pub struct TableData {
    pub id: i32,
    pub itemIds: String
}

pub fn setup_db() -> Result<String, String>{
    let db_connection = match rusqlite::Connection::open("data.sqlite") {
        Ok(connection) => connection,
        Err(_) => {
            return Err("Cannot connect to database.".into());
        }
    };
    match db_connection
        .execute(
            "create table if not exists item (
                id integer primary key,
                name varchar(64) not null,
                preperation_time integer not null
            );
            create table if not exists restaurant_table (
                id integer primary key,
                items varchar(64) not null", 
            []
            ) {
                Ok(success) => Ok("Successfully created database tables.".into()),
                Err(_) => return Err("Could not run create table sql".into())
            }
    }
```

main.rs

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] 
extern crate rocket;

use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use rusqlite::Result;

mod database;
mod data;

#[get("/api/get-all-tables-v1")]
fn get_all_tables() -> Result<Json<data::Table>, String> {
    let db_connection = match rusqlite::Connection::open("data.sqlite") {
        Ok(connection) => connection,
        Err(_) => {
            return Err("Cannot connect to database.".into());
        }
    };

    let mut statement = match db_connection.prepare("select id, items from restaurant_table;") {
        Ok(statement) => statement,
        Err(_) => return Err("Failed to prepare query.".into())
};
let results = statement.query_map([], |row| {
    Ok(database::TableData {
        id: row.get(0)?,
        itemIds: row.get(1)?
    })
});
match results {
    Ok(rows) => {
     ///// This is where I'm stuck on what to do next //////
        let collection: rusqlite::Result<Vec<data::Item>> = rows.collect();
        match collection {
            Ok(items) => Ok(Json(data::Table { items })),
            Err(_) => Err("Could not collect items.".into())
        }
    },
    Err(_) => Err("Failed to fetch items.".into())
}
}

fn main() {
    match database::setup_db() {
        Ok(_) => luanch_server(),
        Err(error) => eprintln!("Program failed to start because of Error {}.", error)
    }
}

fn luanch_server() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![get_all_tables]).launch();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and I will post the code here in case anyone finds it in the future. It is not great code and I ended up not using it but it was a good learning experience.

```
for row in rows.into_iter().flatten() {
            let ids = row.itemIds.split(",");
            for id in ids {
                let mut item_statement = db_connection
                    .prepare("select * from item where id = :id;")
                    .expect("Failed to prepare query.");
                let mut item_rows = item_statement
                    .query_named(rusqlite::named_params!{ ":id": id })
                    .expect("Select item statement failed");
                while let Some(item_row) = item_rows
                    .next()
                    .expect("Row Failed.") {
                        let item = data::Item { 
                            id: row.get(0),
                            time_to_prepare: row.get(1),
                            name: row.get(2)
                        };
                        if !tables.contains(item.id) {
                            tables.insert(item);
                        }
                    }
```